# How to load Switch inside a viewGroup?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Am trying to **load a Switch inside a viewGroup**, all I have done is created a LinearLayout which contains a frameLayout in it. And in the code I have created a class "CustomViewGroup" extending from ViewGroup and added it as a child of the FrameLayout. The **CustomViewGroup has switch as its child**. **But it could is not coming view while loading**. What am I missing?

Here I have attached my code:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myBaseLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            FrameLayout mylayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout> (Resource.Id.myBaseLayout);
            CustomViewGroup cell = new CustomViewGroup (BaseContext);
            Switch myswitch = new Switch (BaseContext);
            myswitch.Checked = true;
            cell.AddView (myswitch);
            mylayout.AddView (cell);
        }
    }
```

CustomViewGroup:

```
public class CustomViewGroup : ViewGroup
    {
        public CustomViewGroup (Context context) : base (context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLayout (bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            var view = GetChildAt (0);
            if (view != null)
                view.Layout (0, 0, this.Width, 40);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the purpose of your custom ViewGroup having exactly one child?

Comment: Well my actual purpose is to create a table view. In that I have created each cell of type ViewGroup, so that anything can be put into the viewGroup.

Comment: Table View in the sense, to display my data in table format, which contains row and cells. That is my actual purpose.